# Converting Detectron2 instance segmentation to opencv Mat array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, data-conversion, detectron

I am trying to get a binary image from the instance segmentation output performed using Detectron2.
According to [the official documentation](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/models.html) the mask's output format is the following:

> “pred_masks”: a Tensor of shape (N, H, W), masks for each detected instance.

So i tried converting it to numpy:
`mask = outputs["instances"].get("pred_masks").numpy()`
The output was the following:

```
[[[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]

 [[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  ...
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]

 [[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  ...
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]

 ...

 [[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  ...
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]

 [[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  ...
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]

 [[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  ...
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]]
```

However the data type was boolean so i added the following line to get closer to the opencv format:
`array = (mask > 126) * 255`

```
[[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]]
```

And that is as far as I went to.
I would like to be able to visualize each mask individually as an opencv image:
`cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)`
, without having to save the image.

[What I would like to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Oy8R.jpg)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will give a solution for what you expecting

```
mask_array = outputs['instances'].pred_masks.numpy()
num_instances = mask_array.shape[0]
mask_array = np.moveaxis(mask_array, 0, -1)
mask_array_instance = []
output = np.zeros_like(im) #black
#print('output',output)
for i in range(num_instances):
    mask_array_instance.append(mask_array[:, :, i:(i+1)])
    output = np.where(mask_array_instance[i] == True, 255, output)
cv2.imwrite(mask_path+'/'+item+'.jpg',output)#mask
```

Comment: It is exactly what I was looking to achieve. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
mask_array = outputs['instances'].pred_masks.to("cpu").numpy()
num_instances = mask_array.shape[0]
scores = outputs['instances'].scores.to("cpu").numpy()
labels = outputs['instances'].pred_classes .to("cpu").numpy()
bbox   = outputs['instances'].pred_boxes.to("cpu").tensor.numpy()

mask_array = np.moveaxis(mask_array, 0, -1)

mask_array_instance = []
#img = np.zeros_like(im) #black
h = im.shape[0]
w = im.shape[1]
img_mask = np.zeros([h, w, 3], np.uint8)
color = (200, 100, 255)
for i in range(num_instances):
    img = np.zeros_like(im)
    mask_array_instance.append(mask_array[:, :, i:(i+1)])
    img = np.where(mask_array_instance[i] == True, 255, img)
    array_img = np.asarray(img)
    img_mask[np.where((array_img==[255,255,255]).all(axis=2))]=color
    
img_mask = np.asarray(img_mask)
output = cv2.addWeighted(im, 0.7, img_mask, 0.3, 0)
```

Comment: How I do to take individual masks?